# Javascript function runs twice when called

Tags: javascript, function, call

So, I'm working on a rich-text editor using contenteditable.
I have a function called "dveditor". I do `var editor = new dveditor()`; pass in some settings, and it replaces the content of a div with stuff.

But it runs twice.
If I remove the `editor = new editor();` It does not run at all.
But if I call it once, it's run twice. I replace the code in the function with only an alert and same thing happens. So the function is not calling itself.

Any ideas what might be wrong? I'm kinda clueless. At least when I know that I'm only calling it once. I mean, if I remove the call to it, it stops completely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see more code, some context may help.

Comment: We cannot help you without seing your current code

Comment: Have you checked you included the javascript file just once in your html?

Comment: I just tried something. on the "page" in my cms I wrote function cake() {alert("cake");} then cake(); it runs twice too!.. weird stuff :S

Comment: Turns out, I should not put <script>s inside content divs that are managed by some other function. It reads the content including <script> and weird stuff happens. I'm gonna always put scripts outside my content divs from now on :P